# Codeigniter APC cache performance

Tags: codeigniter, apc

Today, I installed **APC** on ubuntu server(virtual machine) to test with my CodeIgniter code. I enabled profiling. All thing it did was reducing time from 0.4 sec to 0.32 sec.

APC disabled:

```
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0444
Controller Execution Time       0.3630
Total Execution Time            0.4079
```

APC enabled:

```
Loading Time: Base Classes      0.0439
Controller Execution Time       0.2822
Total Execution Time            0.3265
```

1. Should I expect that much from APC or there is something more that I should obtain by better configuration?
2. Should I change anything in my Codeigniter code?
3. As far as I know APC is a bytecode caching and not page caching nor caching database rows, but [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/caching.html#apc) it seems strangely the author of user-guide is trying to cache the page. And I found no user guide about how to run codeigniter alongside APC.

Comment: what is the structure of your application?

Comment: @Suleman what do you mean by structure of app?

Comment: structure means, either your application is ajax. one more thing that we have done for improving the performance is caching the urls and if same url is hit then load from browser cache, using html5 features.